# '\' character is getting added when executing in graphql

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, graphql

Not able to figure out how i can get rid of '' character. I have tried few things but it didnt work out for me.
I think postgressql changes json string like that.

Comment: That backslash is not part of your data; it's just part of the syntax used to represent the data. If they weren't there the document would not be valid JSON and it couldn't be loaded at all.

Comment: I think I suggested using a JSON column to you in an earlier question; as you are using Postgresql it may be _even better_ to use a [JSONB](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=jsonb#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) column, importable via `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB`

Comment: Yes i did use JSONB this time

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "get rid of" the backslash (`\`) characters because they're not really there. They are escape characters that are required when a double-quoted string literal contains double-quotes within it:

```py
>>> res = "[\"jay\", \"dhar\"]"
>>> print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do realize now that the back slash is a representation and its not coming when i am posting the data. .
Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community :)